# How to modify regex pattern part to apply to tag attributes only

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex that runs in PHP that is picks up `<script>xxxx</script>` and `on...='xxx'` and `data-callback='xxx'` attributes:

```
$regex = '/(<script\b[^><]*>)(.*?)(<\/script>)|\b(on\w+|data-callback)\s*=\s*\K(?|(\')([^\'\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|\'(?=[^)(]*\)))[^\'\\\\]*)*)\'|(")([^"\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|"(?=[^)(]*\)))[^"\\\\]*)*)")/ism';
```

but I've noticed the non `<script>` part is also picking up strings outside of `<...>` tags.

I currently use this regex in the following code:

```
<?php
$regex = '/(<script\b[^><]*>)(.*?)(<\/script>)|\b(on\w+|data-callback)\s*=\s*\K(?|(\')([^\'\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|\'(?=[^)(]*\)))[^\'\\\\]*)*)\'|(")([^"\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|"(?=[^)(]*\)))[^"\\\\]*)*)")/ism';

$html="<script>yyyy</script>\n";
$html.="<a href='nnnn' onClick='yyy' ONF='yyy' data-callback='yyy'>data-callback='nnn'</a>\n";
$html.='<a href="nnn" data-callback="yyy" onClick="yyy">onkeypress=nnn onx="nnn" data-callback="nnn"</a>';

$result = preg_replace_callback($regex,
    function ($matches)  {
    
        if (isset($matches[1])) $m1 = $matches[1];                                else $m1 = "";
        if (isset($matches[2])) $m2 = $matches[2];                                else $m2 = "";
        if (isset($matches[3])) $m3 = $matches[3];                                else $m3 = "";
        if (isset($matches[4])) $m4 = $matches[4];                                else $m4 = "";
        if (isset($matches[5])) $m5 = $matches[5];                                else $m5 = "";
    
        echo "\n<LI>cp : 1[$m1] 2[$m2] 3[$m3] 4[$m4] 5[$m5]";
        
        $m0=substr($m5, 0, 1);
        if ( strcmp($m0, "'")==0 or strcmp($m0, '"')==0 ) $quote=$m0;
        else $quote="";
        
        return $m1.$m0."ZZZZ".$m0.$m3;
        return "$m1$m2=".$quote."ZZZZZ".$quote."";

    }
    , $html);
            
echo "\n\n".$result;
```

which outputs the following :

```
<LI>cp : 1[<script>] 2[yyyy] 3[</script>] 4[] 5[]
<LI>cp : 1[] 2[] 3[] 4[onClick] 5[']
<LI>cp : 1[] 2[] 3[] 4[ONF] 5[']
<LI>cp : 1[] 2[] 3[] 4[data-callback] 5[']
<LI>cp : 1[] 2[] 3[] 4[data-callback] 5[']
<LI>cp : 1[] 2[] 3[] 4[data-callback] 5["]
<LI>cp : 1[] 2[] 3[] 4[onClick] 5["]
<LI>cp : 1[] 2[] 3[] 4[onx] 5["]
<LI>cp : 1[] 2[] 3[] 4[data-callback] 5["]

<script>ZZZZ</script>
<a href='nnnn' onClick='ZZZZ' ONF='ZZZZ' data-callback='ZZZZ'>data-callback='ZZZZ'</a>
<a href="nnn" data-callback="ZZZZ" onClick="ZZZZ">onkeypress=nnn onx="ZZZZ" data-callback="ZZZZ"</a>
```

How can I modify this (the `on|data-callback` part) to only apply only to when they are detected inside `<` and `>`?

I want the following result:

```
<script>ZZZZ</script>
<a href='nnnn' onClick='ZZZZ' ONF='ZZZZ' data-callback='ZZZZ'>data-callback='nnn'</a>
<a href="nnn" data-callback="ZZZZ" onClick="ZZZZ">onkeypress=nnn onx="nnn" data-callback="nnn"</a>
```

I have a running example running on https://onlinephp.io/c/4ab99

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at parsing potentially nested stuff like XML tags. Try to use some XPath expression for that (eg. with SimpleXML)

Answer (score 0):

In `<tags>` (other than `<script> </script>`) you have multiple " attr='xxx'" etc. nested, so the regex have to be also nested to check for `<... attr1='xxx' attr2="yyy"... >` (as you want to separate the meaning of the code inside `<tags>` and outside).

It was not easy ;) but look at https://3v4l.org/45Kvi#v7.4.33

```
<?php
$html="<script>yyyy</script>\n";
$html.="<a href='nnnn' onClick='qqq' ONF='rrr' data-callback='yyy'>data-callback='nnn'</a>\n";
$html.='<a href="nnn" data-callback="xxx" onClick="ppp">onkeypress=nnn onx="nnn" data-callback="nnn"</a>';

$regex = '/
(<script\\b[^><]*>)     # 1
(.*?)                   # 2
(<\\/script>)           # 3
|\\<
([^>]*)                 # 4
\\>
/ismx';

$regex_in_tag = '@\\b
(on\\w+|data-callback)  # 1/original4
\\s*=\\s*               #\\K
(?|
    (\')                # 2/orig.5
    ([^\'\\\\]*         # 3/6
        (?:
            (?:\\\\.|\'
                (?=[^)                (]*\\))
                
            )
            [^\'\\\\]*
        )*
        
    )
    \'|
    (")                 # 2/5
    ([^"\\\\]*          # 3/6
        (?:
            (?:\\\\.|"
                (?=[^)                (]*\\))
                
            )
            [^"\\\\]*
        )*
        
    )
    "
)@ismx';

$result = preg_replace_callback($regex,
    function ($matches)  {
    
        /*
        if (isset($matches[1])) $m1 = $matches[1];                                else $m1 = "";
        ...
        if (isset($matches[5])) $m5 = $matches[5];                                else $m5 = "";
        */
        foreach (range(1, count($matches)) as $value) {
            ${"m$value"} = $matches[$value] ?? '';
        }
    
        //echo "\n<LI>cp : 0[{$matches[0]}] 1[$m1] 2[$m2] 3[$m3] 4[$m4] 5[$m5]";
        
        echo "\n<LI>cp : 0[{$matches[0]}]";
        foreach (range(1, count($matches)) as $value) {
            ${"m$value"} = $matches[$value] ?? '';
            echo " $value".'[', ($matches[$value] ?? ''), "]";
        }
        
        /*
        $m0=substr($m5, 0, 1);
        if ( strcmp($m0, "'")==0 or strcmp($m0, '"')==0 ) $quote=$m0;
        else $quote="";
        
        return $m1.$m0."ZZZZ".$m0.$m3;
        return "$m1$m2=".$quote."ZZZZZ".$quote."";
        */
        if ($m4) {
            preg_match_all($GLOBALS['regex_in_tag'], $m4, $matchs);//echo PHP_EOL;var_export($matchs);
            foreach ($matchs[0] as $key => $value) {
                $m4 = preg_replace('@'.preg_quote($matchs[2][$key].$matchs[3][$key].$matchs[2][$key]).'@', $matchs[2][$key].'zzzz'.$matchs[2][$key], $m4);
            }
            return "<$m4>";
        } else {
            if (isset($m5)) {
                $m0=substr($m5, 0, 1);
                if ( strcmp($m0, "'")==0 or strcmp($m0, '"')==0 ) $quote=$m0;
                else $quote="";
            } else {
                $m0 = $quote = '';
            }
            
            return $m1.$m0."ZZZZ".$m0.$m3;
            return "$m1$m2=".$quote."ZZZZZ".$quote."";
        }

    }
    , $html);
            
echo "\n\n".$result;
?>
```

Result:

```
<script>ZZZZ</script>
<a href='nnnn' onClick='zzzz' ONF='zzzz' data-callback='zzzz'>data-callback='nnn'</a>
<a href="nnn" data-callback="zzzz" onClick="zzzz">onkeypress=nnn onx="nnn" data-callback="nnn"</a>
```